# How to check if a patch remains a state for a certain ticks\time?

Tags: netlogo

Based on the “*sheep eat grass*” model. The patches are changing color with the agents move. I want to check if a patch has remain a centain color for a while (such as 5 ticks). If a patch has stayed in a centain color for a centain times without any change it will turn into black.

I try to use countup but it didn’t work. I need a accumulated state. Thanks a lot

```
If pcolor=green[
Ifelse countup>=5[
Set pcolor black
Set countup 0]
[set countup countup+1]]
```

Comment: can you share what you tried already?

Comment: Hey! I add my code. Sorry for the mess. The question is how to track a patch to see if it remains a state for within a centain time continuely

Answer (score 1):

Can you give a little more detail as to what is going wrong with the code you've shown? For example, with this setup:

```
patches-own [ time-spent-green ]

to setup
  ca
  crt 3 
  reset-ticks
end
```

Something very similar to your example works fine for me:

```
to go 
  ask turtles [
    rt random 61 - 30 
    fd 1
    ask patch-here [
      set pcolor green
    ]
  ]

  ask patches with [ pcolor = green ] [
    ifelse time-spent-green >= 5 [
      set pcolor black
      set time-spent-green 0
    ] [
      set time-spent-green time-spent-green + 1
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

Where the patches stay green for 5 ticks then turn back to black.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your help. The problem is the patches change color all the time randomly. What I want to do is to judge if a patch has stayed in green continually for 5 ticks. Within 5 ticks if it changes into other color it won’t turn into black.

Comment: @Yanxin - Green only, or any color for five ticks in a row?